# how to correctly print json response using python

Tags: python, django

I have json arrays as follows

**payload.json**

```
{"provision":"provision section 1",
       "subsets": [{"item":"milk"},{"payments": [{"price": "170 usd"}]},
                   {"item":"sugar"},{"payments": [{"price": "70 usd"}]}, 
                   {"item":"tea"},{"payments": [{"price": "90 usd"}]}]}
```

Here is the code am using to get the json response

```
import json
import requests
r = requests.get('http://localhost/payload.json')
stat=r.status_code
head=r.headers['content-type']
encode=r.encoding
texting=r.text
result=r.json()

print(stat)
print(head)
print(texting)
print(result)
```

I can successfully get the results in json

**My requirements:** 
How do I successfully loops to print out values for **Provisions**, **item** and **price**.
If i try something like `print(result.provision)`, it will display error **dict object has no attribute provision**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The error you got**:

> dict object has no attribute provision

**The reason**:

Since dict does not have any attribute as such.

**Also**:

As stated already by @RemcoGerlich, now that it is a dict you may access its elemenets by:

```
result = {"provision":"provision section 1",
       "subsets": [{"item":"milk"},{"payments": [{"price": "170 usd"}]},
                   {"item":"sugar"},{"payments": [{"price": "70 usd"}]},
                   {"item":"tea"},{"payments": [{"price": "90 usd"}]}]}

print(result['provision'])
print(result['subsets'])
```

**OR**

```
for k,v in result.items():
    print(k,v)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
provision provision section 1
subsets [{'item': 'milk'}, {'payments': [{'price': '170 usd'}]}, {'item': 'sugar'}, {'payments': [{'price': '70 usd'}]}, {'item': 'tea'}, {'payments': [{'price': '90 usd'}]}]
```

**EDIT**:

Since the `dict_` has elements with lists:

```
result = {"provision":"provision section 1",
       "subsets": [
           {"item":"milk"},
           {"payments": [{"price": "170 usd"}]},
           {"item":"sugar"},
           {"payments": [{"price": "70 usd"}]},
           {"item":"tea"},
           {"payments": [{"price": "90 usd"}]}
       ]
          }
```

Let's say you want to get the first element inside `subsets`:

```
print(result.get('subsets')[0])   # {'item': 'milk'}
```

Where as;

```
print(result.get('subsets')[0].values())    # dict_values(['milk'])
```

Comment: At DirtyBit, Thanks for your response.  Please How Do I get values for item and price. As you can see in items we have milk, tea, sugar and in price we have 170 usd, 70 usd, 90 usd. I have tried this code but with no luck  
# Subsets is a slice so you must loop over it 
for v in result['subsets']:
    print(v['item'])

#within Subsets, payment is also a slice
for s in v['payments']:
  print(v['price'])

Comment: @NancyMooree `print(result['subsets'][0].values())` should give you `milk`

Answer (score 2):

At that point you don't have a JSON object anymore, JSON was simply the way it was transported between the server and you; `r.json()` translates it into a *Python dictionary*.

You access keys of a Python dictionary with e.g. `result['provision']` and you can print that.

That said, as you also tagged this with Django, inside a Django *template* you would still use `result.provision`; that tries several things until it gets a result it can print, including the case where result is a dictionary and provision a key of it.

Comment: At RemcoGerlich, Thanks for your response. Now I can get value for provision.  Please How Do I get values for item and price. As you can see in items we have milk, tea, sugar and in price we have 170 usd, 70 usd, 90 usd. I have tried this code but with no luck  
# Subsets is a slice so you must loop over it 
for v in result['subsets']:
    print(v['item'])

#within Subsets, payment is also a slice
for s in v['payments']:
  print(v['price'])

Comment: @NancyMooree: it all goes a bit far for a SO question, if mine and especially DirtyBit's answer aren't enough then I think you should really spend some more time with the Python tutorial to get familiar with dictionaries, lists, for loops and such.